# Java Operator Precedence and Ternary Operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

The code

```
return "Unexpected Error: " + (e.getMessage() == null ? "No further details!" : e.getMessage());
```

produces my expected result. For example, for an e IndexOutOfBoundsException, I get

```
Unexpected Error: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

However when I remove the extra parentheses surrounding the ternary expression like

```
return "Unexpected Error: " + e.getMessage() == null ? "No further details!" : e.getMessage();
```

I get

```
Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

I am unable to understand the order of evaluation.

Java Version 1.8.0_341-b10 (64 bit)

Comment: It is exactly as you said in the title. This is an operator precedence problem. `+` has higher precedence than `==`.

Comment: in your second snippet, `"Unexpected Error: " + e.getMessage()` gets compared to `null`. Not sure what is unclear here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator, `+` has higher precedence than the operator, `==`

Therefore

```
return "Unexpected Error: " + e.getMessage() == null ? "No further details!" : e.getMessage()
```

is evaluated as follows:

```
if ("Unexpected Error: " + e.getMessage() == null)
    return "No further details!";
else
    return e.getMessage();
```

whereas

```
return "Unexpected Error: " + (e.getMessage() == null ? "No further details!" : e.getMessage());
```

is evaluated as

```
if (e.getMessage() == null)
    return "Unexpected Error: " + "No further details!";
else
    return "Unexpected Error: " + e.getMessage();
```

I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: I'd like to mention that the if...else form is more readable and less likely to cause this kind of confusion anyway, so just use it. Ternary operator might make you feel l33t but it makes life harder on those who read and debug the code.